# JS with EasyPieChart and Waypoint not executing

Tags: javascript, jquery, easypie, waypoint

I have a simple question as I'm not to deep into JS coding.

What is wrong with the following code-snippet and why isn't it executing as expected.
(-> loading the charts as soon as they come into view)

```
var waypoint  = new Waypoint({
  element: document.querySelector("#chartcontainer"),
  handler: function() {
    $(".chart").easyPieChart({
      scaleColor: false,
      lineWidth: 20,
      lineCap: "butt",
      barColor: "#9b0000",
      trackColor: "#ecf0f1",
      size: 160,
      animate: 1500
    });
    $(".count").each(function() {
      var $this = $(this);
      $({ Counter: 0 }).animate({ 
        Counter: $this.text() 
      },{
        duration: 1500,
        easing: "swing",
        step: function() {
          $this.text(Math.ceil(this.Counter));
        }
      });
    });
  }
});
```

I don't understand what I have done wrong with my script. An explanation would be helpful for (maybe) future problems.

For the whole snippet and all the used libraries & frameworks, check out the corresponding codepen:
https://codepen.io/toxicterror/pen/EJPjEQ

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Waypoint actually fires when you scroll past an element. Your pen is most likely not tall enough to allow you to scroll up and down, therefore triggering the Waypoint -> EasyPieChart interaction.

I forked your pen and provided a demo that shows that your code actually works :
https://codepen.io/anon/pen/VOmVrJ

I simply added these lines to your `body` CSS to see that it actually works :

```
  min-height:10000px;
  overflow-y:scroll;
```

In a real life scenario, you most likely won't need it since you're planning on scrolling past this content.

---

EDIT :

If you use the `offset` property of Waypoint, you can actually make sure it gets both triggered on page load, and on page scroll. Try using it like this :

```
var waypoint  = new Waypoint({
  element: document.querySelector("#chartcontainer"),
  offset: $("#chartcontainer").height(),
  handler: function() {
    ...
```

By setting it to the height of the container, you make sure it is fully visible before triggering the animation.

Comment: wow. I feel dumb now :) thanks a lot and a special thank you for the detailed explanation.

Comment: My pleasure! Don't beat yourself up, we all have our struggles ;)